# Symfony 4 + AWS Cloudfront as PageCache + AWS ELB results in endless redirects on frontpage

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I am having the following setup:

```
Domain -> Cloudfront -> ELB -> #instances
```

This fails ONLY (!) on the index page, all sub pages are working fine!
If I remove the Cloudfront in the chain, everything works.

So the server error says "Too many redirects". I am using currently (for testing) the following .htaccess content ("official" example):

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I enabled trace logging for htaccess mod rewrite with the following output if I open the index page with cloudfront.domain.com

```
[rewrite:trace2] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff233f70/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] trying to replace context docroot /var/www/html/web with context prefixerror_log
[rewrite:trace1] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff233f70/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]error_log
[rewrite:trace3] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/web/index.php -> index.php
[rewrite:trace3] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri 'index.php'
[rewrite:trace4] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] RewriteCond: input='/index.php::index.php' pattern='^(/.+)/(.*)::\\\\2$' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace3] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/web/index.php -> index.phperror_log
[rewrite:trace3] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
[rewrite:trace4] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='.' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace3] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/web/index.php -> index.php
[rewrite:trace3] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] applying pattern '^index\\\\.php(?:/(.*)|$)' to uri 'index.php'
[rewrite:trace4] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] RewriteCond: input='200' pattern='^$' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace3] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/web/index.php -> index.php
[rewrite:trace3] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
[rewrite:trace4] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/web/index.php' pattern='-f' => matched
[rewrite:trace1] ... [cloudfront.domain.com/sid#55e9fedd93e0][rid#55e9ff166a68/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/web/] pass through /var/www/html/web/index.php
```

The comments in the .htaccess files say that you should comment the lines if the error with "too many redirects" occurs. But this is not working for me. Cause the problem only occurs with cloudfront in front of the webserver.
Also this setup was working fine with Symfony 3.4!

Any .htaccess server gurus out there who can tell me what is possibly causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself.
The problem seems to be that Cloudfront is adding a slash to the `REQUEST_URI`, which leads to a duplicate `/` on the index page and a redirect to itself and so on.

So my hotfix was to put that at the beginning of the `index.php` file to remove `//` from the `REQUEST_URI`:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/' . ltrim(@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
```